# how do i make the bot do something after i react to its message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have tried to make the bot await a reaction from a user but I don't know how to set it up. I've tried this, I've also put the `const filter` in the first part but when it reacts to the message with 1️⃣ the bot says the reply.

```js
message.channel.send(`the current number is:  ${number}`).then(message => {
    message.react('1️⃣')
    message.react('2️⃣')
    message.react('3️⃣')
});

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['1️⃣', '2️⃣','3️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
        && user.id === message.author.id;
}

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
            message.reply('you reacted with 1');
        } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣') {
            message.reply('you reacted with 2');
        } else {
            message.reply('you reacted with 3');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('game has ended');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js Client objects have the `messageReactionAdd` (along with Remove, RemoveAll and when a bot removes an emoji reaction) event trigger, which gives you a fairly simple solution.

```
let targetUser = "some-long-number"; 
// replace this with the author of the person who fires your 
// reaction related command in your client.on('message') def.
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user)) {
  console.log('sample message to verify base functionality');
  if (user != targetUser) return null;
  switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
    case "1️⃣":
      message.reply("you reacted with 1️⃣");
      break;
    case "2️⃣":
      message.reply("you reacted with 2️⃣");
      break;
    case "3️⃣":
      message.reply("you reacted with 3️⃣");
      break;
    default:
      // in case you want to log when they don't reply with the correct emoji.
      break;
  }
}
```

I've probably mistyped this somewhere, so feel free to correct me.
If `message.reply()` works, my first suggestion is to log the channel ID of the user's command in a global variable (such as `channel-id`), and use `channel-id.send(content);`.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see the Emojis but I'll tell you how I do it (Note: I'm using an async function so I don't have to use plenty of callbacks, I just personally prefer it over `.then` chaining):

```
const msg = await message.channel.send(`the current number is:  ${number}`);
await Promise.all([
    message.react('1️⃣'),
    message.react('2️⃣'),
    message.react('3️⃣')
]);

const filter = (reaction, user) => ['1️⃣', '2️⃣','3️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 120000, max: 1 }); //setup here

collector.on('collect', async () => {
    //... your logic after reaction here
});
```